# Delaunay triangulation : Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was trying to write a code using Delaunay triangulation method and I got a plot with some bunch of triangles. But how can I verify whether what I plotted is correct or not? or whether the triangles are from the desired points or not?

```
 I = bwmorph(I,'skel',Inf);
[i1,j1] = ind2sub(size(I),find(bwmorph(bwmorph(I,'thin',Inf),'branchpoint') == 1));
tri1 = delaunayTriangulation(i1,j1)
figure
triplot(tri1)
```

This is a part of my code where DT was implemented.

Input
[image]

DT

[image]

Comment: how do you define "correct"? Can you provide the image you are using as the input?

Comment: what I meant is I need to verify whether the triangles that are formed are from  the intersection points in the image or not . and how can I confirm that the number of triangles that these intersection points can make is  equal to the number of triangles that are been plotted. I have attached the input as well as the output image

Comment: each of the red pixels in the image is a vertex you supply to the triangulation, right? I do not see how the concept of a triangle relates to the source image.

Comment: yes, the red pixels are the vertex for the triangles. My main aim is to find similar images from database using DT method. I am giving a try to it. I don't know whether it will work out or not. I am just trying to identifying the similar images using the number of bifurcation triplets. So I thought finding the intersection points from the source image which is stored in I and j. And this I and j is used for forming triangles.

Answer (score 1):

To have a visual check you can simply overlay the result of the Delaunay triangulation onto your points with `hold on`. For instance:

```
figure
hold on
scatter(i1,j1, 'r');
triplot(tri1)
```

Best,